# C/C++ - Mac OS X - Check If file exists

Tags: c++, c, macos

What is the best way to check if a file exists, if not create it and write info by using mac
library  <.mach-o/dyld.h>   or other..?

Comment: Are you looking for something more MacOS-specific than `FILE* file = fopen ("filename", "w+");` ?

Comment: Could you give me a example with this code above: If file don't exists, create file and write input.

Comment: There's a good introduction to C's standard I/O model here, with some examples: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/ … or, almost always in the first couple of chapters of any C-language tutorial.

Comment: In C++ there Boost.filesytem which is pretty good :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

Checking if a file exists is trivial - use `stat()` or `access()`, e.g.:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int res = access(path, R_OK);
if (res < 0) {
    if (errno == ENOENT) {
         // file does not exist
    } else if (errno == EACCES) {
         // file exists but is not readable
    } else {
         // uh oh
    }
}
```

Creating a file is similarly trivially - use `open()` or `fopen()`.  Find any good book on C programming, this is *the* most fundamental thing most any book will teach.

But what has `<mach-o/dyld.h>` got to do with it?

Comment: @user1104856 an example for reading a book or searching the web?